# appDelegate set rootViewController and viewWillAppear is not called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is demo ,I set `RootViewController` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,but `viewController`'s `viewWillAppear` is not called! I guess it's because the `NavigationController` added the `ViewController` that the response chain of the message failed?

I know it should be set to

```
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController
```

But I want to know what I set to

```
self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController
```

Why not call `mainViewController`'s `viewWillAppear`? Thank you.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    ViewController *mainViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
}

@end
```

Comment: `self.window.rootViewController = navigationController`

Comment: @mag_zbc its not related to failure of calling viewwillappear

Comment: I know it should be set to self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;But I want to know what I set to self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController; Why not call mainViewController's viewWillAppear? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... interesting.

Keeping the following:

```
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
```

even though it's not used, seems to be stealing the `ViewController's` `viewDidAppear`.

If you comment that line then it works as you want.

i.e:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {        
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    ViewController *mainViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    //Comment the navigationController instantiation
    //UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Maybe the `navigationController` was set to own the `ViewController` but since it's not presented on the screen, neither the `viewDidLoad` nor `viewDidAppear` occurs until later, but... when you reassign the `ViewController` to the window, the internal view loading logic feels `viewDidAppear` is no longer needed to be called.
Maybe a bug or intentional, I don't know.

---

**Note: I don't really have a reason for this behavior. I am just shedding light on what caused it.**